# Find remote and local version numbers, compare them, and download if greater

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a workable solution but it is not presentable/clean for public usage.
The file "version.txt" is both remote and local. The difference is the number:

Remote:

```
17 March 2022
FVWM myExtensions ver. 3.1.4
```

Local:

```
15 March 2022
FVWM myExtensions ver. 3.1.1
```

In my "poor" solution I manually changed the lines into one line for awk to find the last column and sed removing the dots between the number. Both results are made as variables.

```
awk '{print $NF}' download/version.txt > tmpGit.txt
VARgit=`sed 's|[.]||g' tmpGit.txt`
awk '{print $NF}' ~/.fvwm/version.txt > tmpLocal.txt
VARlocal=`sed 's|[.]||g' tmpLocal.txt`

if [ "$VARgit" -gt "$VARlocal" ]; then
  echo "New update available.";
  else
  echo "No update.";
fi
```

I have not found a solution for finding the number in text lines and comparing multiple dot numbers.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) ?

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds some issues with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `grep`, e.g.:

```sh
IFS=. read rmajor rminor rpatch < <(grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' remote.txt)
IFS=. read lmajor lminor lpatch < <(grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' local.txt)

[ $rmajor -gt $lmajor ] && echo "New major version"
[ $rminor -gt $lminor ] && echo "New minor version"
[ $rpatch -gt $lpatch ] && echo "New patchlevel"
```

#### Edit

So to test if `remote.txt` contains a newer version, assuming all version items are numerical, something like this works:

```
if [ $rmajor -gt $lmajor ]; then
  echo "New major version"
elif [ $rmajor -eq $lmajor -a $rminor -gt $lminor ]; then
  echo "New minor version"
elif [ $rmajor -eq $lmajor -a $rminor -eq $lminor -a $rpatch -gt $lpatch ]; then
  echo "New patchlevel"
else
  echo "Remote has same version or older."
fi
```

Comment: I think your general idea of using `grep` is the right one, but I have questions about your flow control. What if, for example, the remote version was 3.4.0 and the local version was 4.0.0? Wouldn't that make your script emit a spurious "new minor version" message? I admit that spelling out the `if`s and `elif`s isn't as nice and terse as your `&&`s. But it _would_ make your script more robust.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU sort for Version-sort:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '/FVWM/{print $NF, FILENAME}' local remote | sort -k1,1Vr
3.1.4   remote
3.1.1   local
```

That tells you the version number in decreasing order and the name of the file containing each version number.

The above was run on these input files:

```
$ head local remote
==> local <==
15 March 2022
FVWM myExtensions ver. 3.1.1

==> remote <==
17 March 2022
FVWM myExtensions ver. 3.1.4
```

Given the above this will print the name of the file that contains the highest version number IF the 2 are different and print nothing otherwise:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '/FVWM/{print $NF, FILENAME}' local remote |
sort -k1,1Vr |
awk '
    { vers[NR]=$1; files[NR]=$0; sub(/[^\t]+\t/,"",files[NR]) }
    END{ if ( vers[1] != vers[2] ) print files[1] }
'
remote
```

so then you can just test if that is the remote file name and if so download.

Answer (score 1):

> finding the number in text line

This is easy to do using regular expression, for example using GNU `AWK`, let `file.txt` content be

```
17 March 2022
FVWM myExtensions ver. 3.1.4
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9.]+[.][0-9.]+"}NF{print $1}' file.txt
```

output

```
3.1.4
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field consting 1 or more of digits or dot, literal dot (hence `[.]` rather than `.`), 1 or more of digits or dot. Then if one or more such field is present in given line do print 1st field (this solution assume you have at most 1 such field in each line)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

> comparing multiple dot numbers

I do not know ready solution for this, but I want to note that this task might seems easy, but it is not unless you can enforce certain restriction. In your example you have `3.1.1` and `3.1.4` that is all elements are `<10` so you will get expected result if you do comparison as for needs for alphabetic ordering. Consider what happens if you have `3.9` and `3.11` - latter will be consider earlier as first difference is at 3rd position and `1` is earlier in alphabet that `9`. This problem is not present if you might enforce that all parts are consisting of exactly one digit.